# Confused about GoogleApiClient argument: clientId

Tags: android, google-api-client, google-console-developer

```java
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0 /* clientId */, this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
```

I am a little bit confused about the `clientId` here. I went to the `Developer Console` and got a `clientId` but it doesn't look anything like what I thought it would be.

The `clientId` I got from the `Developer Console` something looks like:

`123456789098-ra2bgaohfs123asd12a1abc12abba1bb.apps.googleusercontent.com`

I don't understand what I'm supposed to be using. Can anybody give me some clarity what to put in the `clientId` argument?

Comment: I haven't used `enableAutoManage()`.  From the documentation for `Builder`, it looks like `clientId` is simply an integer value that you choose as a unique ID for your `GoogleApiClient`.  If you only have one client in your app, you can probably choose any value--0 or 1 should work.

Comment: please provide more info , what have you tried with more code , and refer to links , or tutorial, references,docs